# Apply CSS to ASP Complete Wizard Step

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

Is there anyway of applying a CSS to this control as currently the title text is plain and not matching the rest of the page?

```
<asp:CompleteWizardStep ID="CompleteWizardStep1"  runat="server" Title="<%$ Resources:lblRegNewUserCompleteText %>">
                    </asp:CompleteWizardStep>
```

I can see a method called ApplyStyleSheetSkin but not really sure this is what im looking for?

**edit**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.completewizardstep.title(v=vs.110).aspx

This is the property im having trouble with, it has a default text of "Complete" and seems to be kept separate from any styling made to the rest of the CompleteSuccess text styling.

Answer (score 0):

You have styling properties on the CreateUserWizard control. for example here i changed the complete step text's back color

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server" CompleteSuccessTextStyle-BackColor="Red" >
        <wizardsteps> 
        <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep1" runat="server"/> 
        <asp:CompleteWizardStep ID="CompleteWizardStep1" runat="server"/> </wizardsteps>
    </asp:CreateUserWizard>
```

Comment: the CompleteWizardStep control contains a property called Title, if I follow your advice above which I was already using everything is styled apart from the 'Title' contained in this control, that stays plain text, and I cannot delete it and have it blank as it sticks the text "Complete" in there by default, I want to style this Title property, everything is already styled as I require using the method you suggested above.

Comment: you can remove it by setting the Title property of the CompleteWizardStep to "" (empty string). is that acceptable?

Comment: if it is not acceptable you can create your own html Template for the CompleteStep and style as you wish. i believe this is the simplest way of doing it

Comment: That's the approach I've gone with (the empty string) although it feels like abit of a 'hack' I don't understand why there isn't a style property for the CompleteWizardStep without having to roll your own template.